# How to post assignment .io on github?

Tags: html, css, git, github, repository

guys I'm supposed to upload assignment for this online course..
I followed the tutorial along exactly but something is not working properly.

https://zwc1625.github.io/coursera-web24/ is the where my repo is published and it's working fine.

but,
https://zwc1625.github.io/coursera-web24/mod_2/
where mod_2 is the assignment folder containing 1 html and 1 css file,
when I try to type in this address in the url 404 comes up

My local drive is up to date with the github repo

Help. New and very frustrated with github, I'm spending so much time with this and making no progress.

Comment: Github can be delayed, hit [Ctrl-F5] to reload the page, or wait some time and try again. And, I hardly dare ask, did you 'commit' the project??

Comment: Oh wait, you need to use the proper URL: https://zwc1625.github.io/coursera-web24/mod_2/module2HTML.html as your file is not named 'index.html' and does not get loaded automatically by the server. Copy the file to 'index.html' and you will see that link 'https://zwc1625.github.io/coursera-web24/mod_2/' will work....

Answer (score 1):

Github will serve a few specifically named files automatically, like 'index.html', 'readme.md' or 'readme'. Most servers will look in the specified folder (https://zwc1625.github.io/coursera-web24/mod_2/) for files named: 'index' or 'default' with a specific extension like 'html', 'asp', 'xhtml'.

As the file in your folder 'mod_2' is called 'module2HTML.html' it will not get served automatically. Consequently, if you want to open that file in your browser, you will need to name it specifically in the URL you enter in the browser addressbar: https://zwc1625.github.io/coursera-web24/mod_2/module2HTML.html

Furthermore, when you did name your file 'index.html' it may be possible that there is a time lag between your 'commit' and Github being able to serve your page. Some patience may be required....